# How can pause slider on cursor hover?

Tags: jquery

I try to create slider with jQuery. 
This is onLoad event code.

```
function Slider(){
        var delay=5500;
        var show=2000;
        var hide=1000;
        $('#1').show("fade",show);
        $('#1').delay(delay).hide("fade",{direction:"left"},hide);
        var n=$('.slider img').size();
        var count=2;
        var t=setInterval(function(){
            $('#'+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},show);
            $('#'+count).delay(delay).hide("fade",{direction:"left"},hide);
            if(count==n){
                count=1;
            }
            else{
                count=count+1;
            }
        },8000);
    }
```

it's work and now, i want to pause it onhover. help me, pls.

Answer (score 0):

Try it for some test.

```
Slider(false);

$(".slider img").hover(
  function() {
    Slider(true);
  }, function() {
    Slider(false);
  }
);

function Slider(pause){
        if(pause){
           return false;
        }
        var delay=5500;
        var show=2000;
        var hide=1000;
        $('#1').show("fade",show);
        $('#1').delay(delay).hide("fade",{direction:"left"},hide);
        var n=$('.slider img').size();
        var count=2;
        var t=setInterval(function(){
            $('#'+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},show);
            $('#'+count).delay(delay).hide("fade",{direction:"left"},hide);
            if(count==n){
                count=1;
            }
            else{
                count=count+1;
            }
        },8000);
    }
```